# Low FPS using OpenCv with PiCamera (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to interface my OpenCV program with my Raspberry Pi PiCamera. Every time I use OpenCV to capture video, it drastically drops the FPS. When I capture video using PiCamera's Library, everything is fine and smooth.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a way to fix it?

**This is my code:**

```py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from PCA9685 import PCA9685
import numpy as np
import cv2

try:


    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 90)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 700)

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# When everything is done, release the capture


except:
    pwm.exit_PCA9685()
    print ("\nProgram end")
    exit()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**This is the error I'm getting:**

[image]

Comment: You appear not to have set the dimensions of your video.

Comment: That fixed my FPS issue... But i still get the error message in terminal. Any Ideas what it means or what might be causing it?Also realized that there's a 0.5 sec delay between real movement and whats projected on the video

Comment: Try changing your loop to just `while True:` without the `cap.isOpened()`. Also please update your code to show what you are actually running.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated my code . i also changed the loop as you said. Your answer somewhat fixed my FPS issue (by giving it dimensions). I realized that setting the FPS  >= 100 throws an exception. Now my main concern is what the initial error message means and why is it getting produced?. Feel free to post your dimensions comment as the answer (its a working solution).

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, those are warnings not errors.
2. Reduce the video dimension. Specify the dimension.
3. `cv2.VideoCapture` has some problems as it buffers the frames, and the frames are queued so if you're doing some processing and the speed is less than the bandwidth of `VideoCapture` the video will be slowed down.

So, here is a bufferless `VideoCapture`.

**video_capture_Q_buf.py**

```
import cv2, queue as Queue, threading, time


is_frame = True
# bufferless VideoCapture


class VideoCaptureQ:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    # read frames as soon as they are available, keeping only most recent one
    def _reader(self):
        while True:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if not ret:
                global is_frame
                is_frame = False
                break
            if not self.q.empty():
                try:
                    self.q.get_nowait()   # discard previous (unprocessed) frame
                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass
            self.q.put(frame)

    def read(self):
        return self.q.get()
```

Using it:

**test.py**

```
import video_capture_Q_buf as vid_cap_q # import as alias
from video_capture_Q_buf import VideoCaptureQ # class import
import time

cap = VideoCaptureQ(vid_path)

while True:

    t1 = time.time()

    if vid_cap_q.is_frame == False:
        print('no more frames left')
        break

    try:
        ori_frame = cap.read()
        # do your stuff
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f'FPS: {1/(t2-t1)}')
```

Comment: Can i pass 0 in as an argument if i want the webcam instead of a saved video?

Comment: Yes, you can. The mechanism is same.

Comment: cv2.imshow('frame',ori_frame) is not displaying anything. Its saying my FPS is between 3 & 4

Comment: Can you check if your webcam is configured properly? Does it also fail with video?

Comment: My webcam is configured correctly. When im testing it with a video, it gives the following errors :   open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: unexpected reference "vid" - ignoring  ---------- isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created